# Как в Git посмотреть список задач с ревизия1 до ревизия2

Tags: git

Есть ли простой способ получить список задач из Git от одной ревизии до другой, когда известно, что в комментарии к комитам указываются номера задач, к примеру по такому шаблону:

`[TASK-NNN]:`

Мне хочется извлечь все `TASK-NNN` и оставить уникальные.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
git log <rev_from>..<rev_to> | grep TASK-
```

Comment: *Useless use of grep*, что не удивительно. `git log --grep...`